# CentOS EC2 Instance Unaccounted for Downtime

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance running CentOS 7.2.1511 (Core) that went down earlier today for 7 hours without any log of an internal event to bring it down (poweroff, reboot, etc). Then, after 7 hours it came back up and was totally healthy. I checked every file in `/var/log/`, a full audit revealed that no such action was taken, but the instance was not logging anything for those 7 hours confirming the downtime. Amazon's EC2 syslog also offered no insight into this. I do not have any alarms set to auto-reboot my instances in the case of a failed health check. Has anyone experienced issues like this with Amazon EC2 before? Is there anyway for me to dig deeper?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would investigate further.  That said, you are now on CentOS 7, hooray you!  That also means that log files usually aren’t going to be found in `/var/log` anymore.  They’ve moved to `journald`.  You can read more about the `journalctl` command here (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs) and here (https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/managing-system-logs-journalctl/) and here (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-Using_the_Journal.html), but you should be using that command to look for more information on how/why your server rebooted.  Stopped ec2 instances aren’t normal, and I would definitely investigate further.

---

Adding, you’ll also have to audit AWS to make sure no one with access to your AWS console rebooted or powered down the instance accidentally.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my system didnt have persistant boot log storage enabled, so I dont have past boot history.

Comment: Is there any other way to find the log information if journald didnt dump it on reboot?

Comment: There isn't. If persistent logging is not enabled, logs are ... non-persistant. On the other hand, the fact that you don't have any journalctl logs confirms the reboot

Comment: Horray for moving to green and clunky system-d are out of place 2ps

Comment: @asdf:  What are your journald settings in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`?  If it is set to auto (which is the default), then `journald` will persist logs in `/run/log/journal`.  But if set to `volatile` you’re out of luck.  @bruno9779:  YMMV, but I like CentOS 7 a lot.